# Akka supervisor strategy for different types of actors

Tags: akka, actor, akka-supervision, error-kernel

I'm using Akka and I want to define my own supervision strategy for User Guardian actor. I've defined two types of actors, called TaskActor and MessageActor. They're instantiated as top-level actors.
I wish the user guardian to apply the following supervision strategy: Stop TaskActor and Resume MessageActor when they throw an Exception (I don't mind what particular type of Exception is thrown). How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following solution:

```
object ActorClassUtil {

  val ACTORS_PACKAGE = "utils.actors."
  val TASK_ACTOR_CLASS_NAME  = ACTORS_PACKAGE + "TaskActor"
  val MSG_ACTOR_CLASS_NAME     = ACTORS_PACKAGE + "MessageActor"


  def getFailedActorClassFrom(e: Exception): String = {

    val stackTrace = e.getStackTrace

    // FQCN (Fully Qualified Class Name)
    stackTrace(0) getClassName

  }

}

class UserGuardianSupervisorStrategy extends SupervisorStrategyConfigurator {
  import ActorClassUtil._

  def create(): OneForOneStrategy = {
    OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 20, withinTimeRange = 1 minute) {
      case _: ActorInitializationException  => Stop
      case _: ActorKilledException          => Stop
      case _: DeathPactException            => Stop

      case exception: Exception =>

        val actorClassName = getFailedActorClassFrom(exception)

        if (actorClassName startsWith TASK_ACTOR_CLASS_NAME)
          Stop
        else
          if (actorClassName startsWith MSG_ACTOR_CLASS_NAME)
            Resume
          else
            Stop

    }
  }
}
```